# How do I configure wpa_supplicant.conf for enable the WPS push-button on android6?

Tags: wifi, android, wpa-supplicant, wps

I have android6 on imx6q board with WL1831wifi module, it's work as WIFI WPS client now.

But, the requirement is I want to configure this (whatever I mention) to act as a WIFI WPS Master(WiFi provider), by using this one I want to connect slaves(camera).

Can you provide some ideas?